# Huge loss of memory from USB boot. Any help?

Tags: usb, uninstall, ram

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 13 on my laptop using an 4Gb USB drive with a bootable .ISO 
However I went to try and format the USB on my desktop(Windows 7 :( ) and now it only has 700Mb
Is there any way to get my 4Gbs back, or have I lost it forever?

EDIT: 21/06/13 Thanks guys, got my USB back

Comment: Maybe you formatted *one* partition. Boot into Ubuntu, plug in your USB, open Disks (click on the Dash and search for 'disks'). In Disks click on the icon for your USB drive and see if there is more than one partition.

Comment: If you want to format on Windows, better ask on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a little bit more your problem? The only thing I have in mind is that when you formatted your USB, you problably changed its size to 700mb... Try reformatting it and using the default format option in Windows, and check the options on the window...

(Psss... I can't show it with images, I'm not running Windows but Ubuntu)

Comment: Well I used the program PowerISO to create a bootable USB containing the ISO for Ubuntu. Followed the instructions and installed it fine on my laptop and it works great. However I kind of need the USB back to move some notes around but it formatted to 793Mb. Whenever I try to format it on my desktop(running Windows 7) it can only format to 793Mb in the capacity field in the top of the window. Is there any way I can get round this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried formatting it from Ubuntu?

1. Install gparted: `sudo apt-get install gparted`
2. Plug in your USB drive, unmount it in Nautilus (file manager)
3. Run it from unity, you'll have to give it root access by password
4. In the top right, select the correct drive. This should be obvious after you check the drive layout for each one and the size
5. If the drive is OK, then it should list multiple partitions and total size should be 4GB.
6. Delete all the partitions, reformat them all as one large FAT32 partition
7. Save the changes

**NOTE:** You WILL lose all of your data on the drive by following these steps